# Deleting/changing path to log file throws an error. How do I ignore or fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, atexit

What I want to do is I want to create a folder containing all my logs with the start and end datetime of my script as the title. The problem is- when the program is running I obviously wouldn't know when the script is stopped until it does. So when the script ends, I change the name of the folder I am writing my logs to.

I know I could do this in other ways like just moving all my logs to the folder after the script is done or just NOT have the folder named using the datetimes, etc, etc. But I want to know how to do this for experience on how to catch these sorts of errors and how to work with the logger. Is that a wrong way to go about it?

```
# Creating root logger and script logger
if logger_enabled:
    root_log_level = logging.INFO
    # Making a folder with the date as the name
    time_ran = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    log_folder = "./logs/{time_ran} (running)".format(time_ran=time_ran)
    os.mkdir(log_folder)
    # Setting up root log
    logging.basicConfig(filename=log_folder + "/root.log",
                        format="%(name)s: %(filename)s on %(lineno)d @ %(asctime)s\
                        \n\t%(levelname)s: %(message)s",
                        level=root_log_level)
    # Other stuff
    logging.info("The log level is set at {level}".format(level=root_log_level))
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    print("\033[33mLogger created and configured\033[0m")

def exit_function():
    if logger_enabled:
        exit_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        # This try/except doesn't work. This renaming throws an error because the logger's old file path ceases to exist (because I change the name)
        try:
            # Renaming folder to contain the start and end time of the script
            os.rename(log_folder,
                        "./logs/{time_ran} to {exit_time}".format(time_ran=time_ran, exit_time=exit_time))
        except FileNotFoundError:
            pass

atexit.register(exit_function)
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method Task.__del__ of <Task finished coro=<_run_event() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/discord/client.py:304> exception=SystemExit('Stop command run',)>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 93, in __del__
    futures.Future.__del__(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 215, in __del__
    self._loop.call_exception_handler(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1177, in call_exception_handler
    exc_info=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1308, in error
    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1415, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1425, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1487, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 855, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1047, in emit
    self.stream = self._open()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/__init__.py", line 1037, in _open
    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/hugernot/Desktop/PVSupportSlave/Code/logs/2018-06-09 17:50:35.563516 (running)/root.log'
```

This is what I'm aiming for

[image] 
(Picture of log folders)

Comment: If I see this correctly, the error isn't in the `exit_function` function, but somewhere where you are working with `asyncio`

Comment: Can you, uh... *not* label this as an "inactive" project?  While we don't yet have a good way to label projects like this, adding it to the title is definitely not the best way.

Comment: The problem is that directory name contains spaces and shell reserved characters: `2018-06-09 17:50:35.563516 (running)`. Try with `2018-06-09T17:50:35.563516_running` or if you insist, escape  those characters: `2018-06-09\ 17:50:35.563516\ \\(running\\)'.